Can porcelain tile be stored in an attic which will exceed 100 °F?
I need to store spare tile in my Florida attic.  Is there a temperature issue when storing ceramic or porcelain tile?

If you have a lot, get a chunk of wood that spans a couple of joists and place everything over an interior wall.

@fraxinus Fair enough; on the other hand, there is a difference between long-term exposure like for months in the attic, and a few minutes every day wit the teapot.  For example, if you ask "can I expose my plastic item to direct sunlight" the answer depends on "minutes or months?". Conceivably, the white porcelain could acquire a yellow hue or something like that (it won't, of course, but it's not necessarily a given).

Don't store them with the porous side in contact with something that will be affected by high temperatures, such as candles, as that could permeate through the unglazed surface and affect its ability to be stuck. I have no idea why you might put tiles on/under candles in an attic, but strange things do happen.

Yes.
The tiles are heated to around 2500 degrees during manufacturing.  They can be stored at any temperature you would find in a home.  If they have been hand-painted or otherwise modified at home it would be different.

Even hand painted tiles are fired, are they not?

Hand painted at time of making yes.  Takes me back 50 years to art class.  At least I passed.

@freeman they can/should be. ;)

Note that "any temperature" means any temperature.  Storing them in your oven should be fine.

@Mark I should have caveated that you don't live in a volcano. :)
